# How to launch executable embedded within Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am building an Eclipse plug-in that have to parse the result of an executable (Linux) to display informations to the user. The executable should be embedded in the plug-in, not installed apart.

I first made a small prototype, in which I've embedded a fake executable, then before launching the executable, I extract it into a temporary file, build my command line and then launch it. That worked ok for me.

I've just received the real executable, and then realised it was not a standalone executable, but a bunch of libraries, config files and such. It comes also with a script to execute in order to set env variables.

The only option I am seeing now is to extract the whole bunch to a temp directory, set the environment variables according to the script, and then call my executable.

Is my solution valid ? Do you think of a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't package the plugin as a jar, instead just use a directory so you don't have to do any unpacking.

You specify this using

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

in the plugin MANIFEST.MF.

Note: if you package your plugins in a feature then this setting is overridden by the `unpack="true"` attribute of the `plugin` element in the `feature.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks once again @greg-449. I hope I'll get the chance one day to offer you a beer.